# Update key name in a dictionary python

Tags: python, dictionary, iteration, fasta

I have the following fasta file in a dictionary, in the following shape:

```
from Bio import SeqIO

alignment_file = '/Users/dissertation/Desktop/Alignment 4 sequences.fasta'

seq_dict = {rec.id : rec.seq for rec in SeqIO.parse(alignment_file, "fasta")}
```

Which gives me the following input:

```
{'NC_000962.3': Seq('ctgttaccgagatttcttcgtcgtttgttcttggaaagacagcgctggggatcg...NNN'),
 'NC_008596.1': Seq('------------------------------------------------------...ccg'),
 'NC_009525.1': Seq('ctgttaccgagatttcttcgtcgtttgttcttggaaagacagcgctggggatcg...NNN'),
 'NC_002945.4': Seq('ctgttaccgagatttcttcgtcgtttgttcttggaaagacagcgctggggatcg...NNN')}
```

The only issue here is that I would like to replace the key names for other than easier to identify when comparing the sequences to other parts of my code. So I have tried the following:

```
name_list = ['Tuberculosis', 'Smegmatis', 'H37Ra', 'Bovis']

for key in seq_dict:
    for name in name_list:
        seq_dict[name[x]]= seq_dict[key]
    
seq_dict
```

However I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/pq/ghtv3wj159j681vy0ny3tz9w0000gp/T/ipykernel_47822/1486954832.py in <module>
      9
---> 10 for key in seq_dict:
     11     for name in name_list:
     12         seq_dict[name[x]]= seq_dict[key]

RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
```

I understand that there's not an easy straight forward way of updating key names values in a dictionary, but I don't understand the error. Is there a way of doing something similar?

I have also tried this:

```
seq_dict.update({'NC_000962.3': 'Tuberculosis', 'NC_008596.1': 'Smegmatis', 'NC_009525.1': 'H37Ra', 'NC_002945.4': 'Bovis'})
```

But this gives me the following output:

```
{'NC_000962.3': 'Tuberculosis',
 'NC_008596.1': 'Smegmatis',
 'NC_009525.1': 'H37Ra',
 'NC_002945.4': 'Bovis'}
```

My desire output would look like this:

```
{'Tuberculosis': Seq('ctgttaccgagatttcttcgtcgtttgttcttggaaagacagcgctggggatcg...NNN'),
 'Smegmatis': Seq('------------------------------------------------------...ccg'),
 'H37Ra': Seq('ctgttaccgagatttcttcgtcgtttgttcttggaaagacagcgctggggatcg...NNN'),
 'Bovis': Seq('ctgttaccgagatttcttcgtcgtttgttcttggaaagacagcgctggggatcg...NNN')}
```

Does anybody have an idea on how to update these?

Comment: `for k in list(d.keys()):` will allow you to add the new items; you'll still have to remove the original keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Construct a new dictionary and then assign it to `seq_dict` in a single operation, rather than mutating `seq_dict` as you're in the process of iterating over it.  I think this is what you're aiming for:

```
seq_dict = dict(zip(name_list, seq_dict.values()))
```

although I'd personally want to have an explicit mapping from sequence IDs to names rather than relying on the ordering being the same.

Comment: Both your first and second answer worked perfectly! You're absolutely right than relying on the ordering may not be the best way forward if the dictionary is bigger. But for this occasion, being the dictionary so small, I think this works really well! Thank you